# Blocking ?page= in robots.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, seo, robots.txt

Basically Google is trying to index thousands of articles that all look something like this:

`/questions/are-eggs-bad-for-you?page=69`

The urls range from `page=1` to `page=99` due to my pagination and infinite scroll.

How can I include just the `?page=` part of the url in my robots.txt file so it does not index anything with a page number?

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question, but I am having an overly hard time finding an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Google, preferably do it through [google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), go Crawl-> URL Parameters:

[image]

Add a parameter `page`, choose its effect as `Paginate` and Crawl only `Value=1`

Read more about [Search Console Help - Learn the impact of duplicate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?rd=1)